In what order are expressions evaluated in a test clause of if or when?
In what order is an if or when expression evaluated? In this real life example
<xsl:when test="(wd:Worker_group/wd:CostngAllcExists = '1') and exists(wd:Worker_group/wd:CostngAllcExists) and (wd:Job_Category/@wd:Descriptor = 'PHYSICIAN')">
Is it a stack or queue?
E.G.
wd:Job_Category/@wd:Descriptor = 'PHYSICIAN'
then
exists(wd:Worker_group/wd:CostngAllcExists)
then
(wd:Worker_group/wd:CostngAllcExists = '1')
or the other way?
I would like to test if an element exists before checking for its value. Or, am I over-engineering?
I'm still on a learning curve.
Thanks
